# HTML input inside table takes some extra space — CSS

Tags: html, css

I got the following problem:

[image]

I constantly have little space (light blue colour is space) at the bottom of my form. 
Here is the HTML code that I use:

```
 <table id="wysz">
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 218px; height: 36px; padding: 0px;"><img src="grafa/wyszukiwara/Wysz1.jpg"></td>
    <td style="width: 253px; height: 4px; padding: 0px;"><img src="grafa/wyszukiwara/WyszGora.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 47px; height: 36px; padding: 0px;"><img src="grafa/wyszukiwara/WyszLupa.jpg"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0px; "><form ><input style="width: 253px; height: 29px; border-style: none; display:block;" name="query" ></form ></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td style="width: 253px; height: 3px; padding: 0px; "><img  src="grafa/wyszukiwara/WyszDol.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#wysz{
    border:0px solid black;
    padding:0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 513px;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: scroll;
    vertical-align: top;

}
#wysz td{
    border:0px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
table,th,td
{
    border:0px solid black;
    background-color:lightblue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I did not past all of my code but only that seems to be important.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form element is generating its own margin at the bottom.  Add the following style to the form to reduce it to 0px

```
style="margin-bottom: 0px;"
```